Find maximum length of up then down and up sequence of numbers
I have a list of integers as input, the order of items in input is not important.
I need to form a new list having size n with the below features.
Here i, j represents the index position of the output list such that i < j < n
Items from 0 to i should be in increasing order strictly

Items from i to j should be in decreasing order strictly

Items from j to n should be in increasing order strictly

The new list must satisfy the above properties, and it need not have all the elements from the original input list.
Example 1:
input  [2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3]
valid output sequence with max selected items is [1,2,3,2,1,2,3]
size of this output sequence is 7, so return the value 7

Explanation:
increasing from position 0 to 2 => [1,2,3]
decreasing from position 2 to 4 => [3,2,1]
again increasing from position 4 to last index => [1,2,3]

Example 2:
input  [5, 5, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5]
valid output sequence with max selected items is [1, 3, 5, 4, 2, 5]
size of this output sequence is 6, so return the value 6

Explanation:
increasing from position 0 to 2 => [1,3,5]
decreasing from position 2 to 4 => [5,4,2]
again increasing from position 4 to last index => [2,5]

Example 3:
input  [1, 3, 5, 4, 2, 6, 8, 7, 9]

Output: 9 

Example 4:
input = [1,100]

for this input we can get the updated sequence as [100, 1]

a) increasing part = [100], here i = 0
b) decreasing part = [100, 1], here i=0, j=1
c) increasing part = [1], here j to end, j = 1

Observations: The last item in increasing part is same as first item of decreasing part in above discussion (i.e (a) and (b) groups), similarly the last item of decreasing part is same as first item of increasing part (i.e. (b) and (c) groups)
Constraints:
2 <= input size <= 105
1 <= input element <= 109
input contains at least 2 unique elements.
The program should return the size of the output sequence.
I tried to solve this using a TreeMap:
public static int solve(List<Integer> list) {
        int n = list.size();
        TreeMap<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for(int e : list) {
            min = Math.min(min, e);
            map.put(e, map.getOrDefault(e, 0)+1);
        }
        int result = 1;
        map.put(min, map.getOrDefault(min,0)-1);
        if(map.get(min) <=0) map.remove(min);
        while(true) {
            Integer key = map.higherKey(min);
            if(key == null) break;
            map.put(key, map.getOrDefault(key,0)-1);
            if(map.get(key) <=0) map.remove(key);
            min = key;
            result++;
        }
        int max = min;
        while(true) {
            Integer key = map.lowerKey(max);
            if(key == null) break;
            map.put(key, map.getOrDefault(key,0)-1);
            if(map.get(key) <=0) map.remove(key);
            max = key;
            result++;
        }
        
        min = max;
        while(true) {
            Integer key = map.higherKey(min);
            if(key == null) break;
            map.remove(key);
            min = key;
            result++;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(solve(List.of(1, 3, 5, 4, 2, 6, 8, 7, 9))); // Expected output: 9

        System.out.println(solve(List.of(5, 5, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5))); // Expected output: 6

        System.out.println(solve(List.of(1, 100))); // Expected output: 2
        
        System.out.println(solve(List.of(2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3))); // Expected output: 7
    }

The code fails for input 5, 5, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, it returns 5 as output instead of 6. This is due to my generated array becoming [1,2,3,4,5] with 5 items also not following increasing-decreasing-increasing pattern
So I am using wrong approach to solve this problem, what is the correct approach to solve this problem.

Where do i and j come from  or are determined?  Please show one example, step by step, of how one arrives at the solution.   If this is a code challenge, please provide a link.

"Here i, j represents the index position of the input list such that i < j < n": Did you mean the index position of the output list? I don't see how it makes sense when applied to the input list.

"size of this output sequence is 7, so return the value 6": you lost me. Why? Is this a typo?

You speak of an output sequence, but also of a return value. Do you really need both, or just the return value? If the latter, then I wouldn't call that an output sequence to avoid misunderstandings. Can you address these points in an edit?

@trincot, I corrected all the typo errors now, thanks for pointing them. also, I just need to return the count as a result, output sequence is not needed.  Also, order of input items is not important.

Why for List.of(1, 100) the expected result is 2?

@trincot, I added explanation to my post now for input [1,100]

Oh, so two parts can actually be the same part. I see...

@trincot, I added more details to avoid confusion. part 1 is [100], part 2 is [100,1], part 3 is [1]

(With 0 <= i < j < n, the one part with length always greater 1 is the decreasing part.)

After establishing occurrence counts, I don't think you need to construct the list or the monotonous parts to know the max total length.

" it need not have all the elements from the original input list"  This cannot be true!  If it were then the trivial solution is select the smallest input number, append the largest number, append any other number - j = 2 ( 1-based )

@CodeCrusader I agree that your accepted answer below is the best one, but I'm curious about knowing where did you come across to this problem. Is it some kind of exam-like problem or a real-life situation?

Observations
We need at least two distinct values to have a solution -- if this is not the case we cannot satisfy the constraints, namely that "Items from i to j should be in decreasing order strictly" and "i < j".
The maximum value is a good value to use at index , and the minimum value at index . All other distinct values can be used once between those two indices, forming the middle, descending section. If there are copies of these "other" values, they can be used once more in the first, ascending section, and again in the third, ascending section, meaning that we can use up to three occurrences of the same value. This is not so for the minimum and maximum value. The maximum (it index ) can only be used again as the ending value of the third section, while the minimum (at index ) can only be used again as the starting value of the first section, meaning those two values can be used up to twice only.
It is not needed to actually build the new list as we only need to return the size of that list.
Algorithm
With these observations we get to this algorithm:

Count all occurrences (frequencies) of each distinct value.
Identify the minimum value: it can be used at most twice in  result.
Similarly for the maximum value.
All other values can be used at most 3 times.
Sum all the frequencies taking those limits into account.

Suggested code
    public static int solve(List<Integer> list) {
        Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> min, max;

        // Get all frequencies
        Map<Integer, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();
        list.forEach(s -> counts.merge(s, 1, Math::addExact));

        if (counts.size() < 2) return 0; // No solution
        
        // Get minimum and its frequency, and use at most 2 copies
        min = Collections.min(counts.entrySet(), Map.Entry.comparingByKey());
        counts.remove(min.getKey());
        int result = Math.min(2, min.getValue());

        // Similar approach for the maximum:
        max = Collections.max(counts.entrySet(), Map.Entry.comparingByKey());
        counts.remove(max.getKey());
        result += Math.min(2, max.getValue());

        // All other values can be used at most 3 times
        for (int count : counts.values()) {
            result += Math.min(3, count);
        }        
        return result;
    }

Time Complexity
I've not used a (sorted) TreeMap here, as processing all input values into a TreeMap would lead to a O(log) complexity. Using a HashMap we can achieve a linear time complexity for this process.
Finding both minimum and maximum again represents O() time complexity (in the worst case where all  input values are distinct), and also the final loop to accumulate the result has a linear time complexity.
This brings the total time complexity to O().
NB: in practice the overhead of the repeated iteration over the values may make the benefit over using a sorted container only apparent for very large inputs.


You sort your array.
go from smallest to largest collecting unique elements.
When reach largest you go back collecting left unique elements. If there is none you remove any (except biggest) two element from list collected on previous pass and append them to the end of result and call it a day.
Now you go up again. If there is no element left you need to borrow one from one of previous passes and put it at the end.

Check for corner cases when there is not enough elements. You need at least 5 distinct elements.
EDIT Here is the codez. Didn't test it properly.
    @Test
    public void testApp() {
        List<Integer> input = List.of(2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3);
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(input);
        list.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());
        Iterator<Integer> iterator = list.iterator();
        int current = iterator.next();
        var up = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        var down = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        var up2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        up.add(current);
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            int i = iterator.next();
            if (i != current) {
                iterator.remove();
                up.add(i);
                current = i;
            }
        }
        iterator = list.reversed().iterator();
        if (iterator.hasNext()) {
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                int i = iterator.next();
                if (i != current) {
                    iterator.remove();
                    down.add(i);
                    current = i;
                }
            }
            iterator = list.iterator();
            if (iterator.hasNext()) {
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    int i = iterator.next();
                    if (i != current) {
                        iterator.remove();
                        up2.add(i);
                        current = i;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (down.size() > 1) {
                    up2.add(down.remove(down.size() - 2));
                } else {
                    int x1 = up.remove(up.size() - 2);
                    int x2 = down.remove(0);
                    up2.add(Math.max(x1, x2));
                    down.add(Math.min(x1, x2));
                }
            }
        } else {
            up2.add(up.remove(up.size() - 2));
            down.add(up.remove(up.size() - 2));
        }

        List<Integer> result = Stream.of(up, down, up2)
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .toList();

        assertThatList(result)
                .containsExactly(1,2,3,2,1,2,3);
    }


You need at least 5 distinct elements , we can have a valid combination using [1,3,2] also with 3 items right, so why do we need 5 distinct elements

If you consider one element to be list with increasing order then yes, You only need 3.

can you please provide pesudo code for this approach

@CodeCrusader added some codez

When I am testing the answer with the test cases I added to my post, the answer is not giving correct results.

(@CodeCrusader I numbered the examples; can you please name one example failing?)

@greybeard, try with input 1, 3, 5, 4, 2, 6, 8, 7, 9

Disclaimer & caveat: I am no reputable source, neither on algorithms nor on program source code.
One simple approach just classifies the numbers as occurring once, twice, or three times at least:
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.SortedSet;

public class MaxUpDownUp {
    /**
     * @returns the maximum length of any sequence
                 from <code>values</code> going strictly up-down-up
     */
    // Idea:
    // unique values in descending order are a valid "down" sequence.
    // *possible* additions are values appearing at least twice
    // and values appearing (at least) three times.
    // The "pivot" element being common to the initial up and down
    //  can't occur three times, same for down and final up
    static int maxUpDownUp(List<Integer> values) {
        // numbers seen at least
        SortedSet<Integer>       once = new java.util.TreeSet<>();
        Set<Integer>             twice = new java.util.HashSet<>(),
                                 thrice = new java.util.HashSet<>();
        for (Integer i: values)
            if (!once.add(i) && !twice.add(i))
                thrice.add(i);
        int total = once.size() + twice.size() + thrice.size();
        // neither top nor bottom value can appear three times
        for (int pivot: List.of(once.getFirst(), once.getLast()))
            if (thrice.contains(pivot))
                total -= 1;

        return total;
    }

    public static int solve(List<Integer> values) {
        return maxUpDownUp(values);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[][][] testCases = {
                { { 1, 3, 5, 4, 2, 6, 8, 7, 9 }, { 9 } },
                { { 5, 5, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5 }, { 6 } },
                { { 1, 100 }, { 2 } },
                { { 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3 }, { 7 } }
            };
        
        for (Integer[][] testCase: testCases) {
            List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(testCase[0]);
            System.out.println("expect: " + testCase[1][0]
                + ", getting " + solve(numbers) + " for " + numbers);
        }
    }
}


can you please add more deatils, how this logic can solve this problem. Also when i try to run the code I am getting errors saying method not found for getFirst and getLast

Can you put the finger to where the Idea:  comment is lacking?

I am not able to understand neither top nor bottom value can appear thrice

(Obvious lies in the eye of the beholder …)

This code silently relies on the input meeting the constraints - not a good thing. (Not improving this 'cause it took trincot's answer to make me feel bad about it.)

The greatest length of the solution seems be the size of the problem minus the number of values that can't be used: for the lowest and highest values you can use only 2 occurrence of each and for the values between these you can only use max. 3 of each distinct ones.
So for [1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3] you are losing 1 "1", 1 "3" and you can only use 3 of the 4 "2", so max is 7, but for [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4] you are losing 1 "1" and 1 "4" but you don't lose any middle values, so the max is 8.
And for [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] you don't lose any values so the max is 10.
Generating a solution is another problem because you may have plenty of solutions for the same input, so either you want them all or you have more criteria to define...
@Test
public void testSolveProblem() {
    List<Integer> solution ;
    
    solution = solveProblem(new Integer[] { 1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3 }, false);
    System.out.println("solution: " + solution);
    solution = solveProblem(new Integer[] { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 }, false);
    System.out.println("solution: " + solution);
}

@SuppressWarnings("boxing")
private List<Integer> solveProblem(final Integer[] problem, final boolean debug) {
    System.out.println("problem: " + Arrays.toString(problem));
    Map<Integer, Integer> occurrences = new HashMap<>();
    Integer minOfProblem= Integer.MAX_VALUE, maxOfProblem = Integer.MIN_VALUE, orgMaxOfProblem ;
    
    Set<Integer> bag1 = new HashSet<>();
    Set<Integer> bag2 = new HashSet<>();
    Set<Integer> bag3 = new HashSet<>();
    
    for(Integer i : problem) {
        if (minOfProblem > i)
            minOfProblem = i ;
    
        if (maxOfProblem < i)
            maxOfProblem = i ;
        
        if (occurrences.containsKey(i)) {
            Integer v = occurrences.get(i);
            occurrences.put(i, v+1) ;
        }
        else {
            occurrences.put(i, 1) ;
        }
    }
    orgMaxOfProblem = maxOfProblem;
    
    if (debug) {
        System.out.println("original: " + occurrences);
        System.out.println(minOfProblem + " / " + maxOfProblem);
    }
    
    occurrences.put(minOfProblem, Integer.min(2, occurrences.get(minOfProblem)));
    occurrences.put(maxOfProblem, Integer.min(2, occurrences.get(maxOfProblem)));
    
    for(Integer k : occurrences.keySet()) {
        if (k.equals(minOfProblem) || k.equals(maxOfProblem)) 
            continue;
        occurrences.put(k, Integer.min(3, occurrences.get(k)));
    }
    if (debug) {
        System.out.println("after clipping: " + occurrences);
    }
    
    bag1.add(minOfProblem);
    if (occurrences.get(minOfProblem) > 1)
        occurrences.put(minOfProblem, occurrences.get(minOfProblem)-1);
    else
        occurrences.remove(minOfProblem);
    
    bag1.add(maxOfProblem);
    if (occurrences.get(maxOfProblem) > 1)
        occurrences.put(maxOfProblem, occurrences.get(maxOfProblem)-1);
    else {
        occurrences.remove(maxOfProblem);
        Integer keySet[] = occurrences.keySet().toArray(new Integer[] {});
        Arrays.sort(keySet);
        maxOfProblem = keySet[keySet.length - 1];
    }

    if (debug) {
        System.out.println("after bag1: " + occurrences);
    }
    
    if (occurrences.get(maxOfProblem) > 0) {
        bag3.add(maxOfProblem);
        Integer keySet[] = occurrences.keySet().toArray(new Integer[] {});
        Arrays.sort(keySet);
        Integer secondToGreatest = keySet[keySet.length-2];

        if (occurrences.get(maxOfProblem) > 1)
            occurrences.put(maxOfProblem, occurrences.get(maxOfProblem)-1);
        else
            occurrences.remove(maxOfProblem);           
        
        if (!secondToGreatest.equals(minOfProblem)) {               
            bag3.add(secondToGreatest);
            if (occurrences.get(secondToGreatest) > 1)
                occurrences.put(secondToGreatest, occurrences.get(secondToGreatest)-1);
            else
                occurrences.remove(secondToGreatest);               
        }
    }
    else {
        Integer keySet[] = occurrences.keySet().toArray(new Integer[] {});
        Arrays.sort(keySet);

        maxOfProblem = keySet[keySet.length-1];
        if (debug) {
            System.out.println("new maxOfProblem: " + maxOfProblem);
        }
        
        occurrences.put(maxOfProblem, occurrences.get(maxOfProblem)-1);
        if (occurrences.get(maxOfProblem) == 0)
            occurrences.remove(maxOfProblem);           
        
        Integer secondToGreatest = keySet[keySet.length-2];
        if (!secondToGreatest.equals(minOfProblem)) {               
            bag3.add(secondToGreatest);
            if (occurrences.get(secondToGreatest) > 1)
                occurrences.put(secondToGreatest, occurrences.get(secondToGreatest)-1);
            else
                occurrences.remove(secondToGreatest);               
        }           
    }
    if (debug) {
        System.out.println("after bag3: " + occurrences);
    }
    
    // fill bag2 with 1 occurrence of each middle + minOfProblem
    Integer keySet[] = occurrences.keySet().toArray(new Integer[] {});
    Arrays.sort(keySet);

    for(int idx = 0; idx < keySet.length - 1 ; idx++) {
        bag2.add(keySet[idx]);
        
        occurrences.put(keySet[idx], occurrences.get(keySet[idx])-1);
        if (occurrences.get(keySet[idx]).equals(0))
            occurrences.remove(keySet[idx]);
    }
    if (!orgMaxOfProblem.equals(keySet[keySet.length - 1])) {
        bag2.add(keySet[keySet.length - 1]);
        
        occurrences.put(keySet[keySet.length - 1], occurrences.get(keySet[keySet.length - 1])-1);
        if (occurrences.get(keySet[keySet.length - 1]).equals(0))
            occurrences.remove(keySet[keySet.length - 1]);
    }
    // take remaining occurrences and put them in bag they are not yet
    if (debug) {
        System.out.println("Before looping: " + occurrences);
    }
    boolean hasChanged = false ;
    while (!occurrences.isEmpty() && !hasChanged) {
        keySet = occurrences.keySet().toArray(new Integer[] {});
        
        for(int idx = 0; idx < keySet.length ; idx++) {
            if (!bag1.contains(keySet[idx]) ) {
                bag1.add(keySet[idx]);
                occurrences.put(keySet[idx], occurrences.get(keySet[idx]) - 1);
                if (occurrences.get(keySet[idx]).equals(0))
                    occurrences.remove(keySet[idx]);
                hasChanged = true;
            }
            else if (!bag2.contains(keySet[idx]) && !orgMaxOfProblem.equals(keySet[idx])) {
                bag2.add(keySet[idx]);
                occurrences.put(keySet[idx], occurrences.get(keySet[idx]) - 1);
                if (occurrences.get(keySet[idx]).equals(0))
                    occurrences.remove(keySet[idx]);
                hasChanged = true;
            }
            else if (!bag3.contains(keySet[idx])) {
                bag3.add(keySet[idx]);
                occurrences.put(keySet[idx], occurrences.get(keySet[idx]) - 1);
                if (occurrences.get(keySet[idx]).equals(0))
                    occurrences.remove(keySet[idx]);
                hasChanged = true;
            }
        }
        if (debug) {
            System.out.println("In looping: " + occurrences);
        }
    }

    if (debug) {
        System.out.println("At end: " + occurrences);
        System.out.println(bag1);
        System.out.println(bag2);
        System.out.println(bag3);
    }
    
    List<Integer> solution = new ArrayList<>();
    Integer values[] = bag1.toArray(new Integer[] {});
    Arrays.sort(values);
    for(int idx = 0 ; idx < values.length ; idx++)
        solution.add(values[idx]) ;
    
    values = bag2.toArray(new Integer[] {});
    for(int idx = values.length - 1 ; idx >= 0 ; idx--)
        solution.add(values[idx]) ;
    
    values = bag3.toArray(new Integer[] {});
    for(int idx = 0 ; idx < values.length ; idx++)
        solution.add(values[idx]) ;
    
    return solution ;
}

